# Codeigniter anchor around div tag

Tags: codeigniter, html, hyperlink, anchor

How can we use function anchor of codeigniter for div tag?

I got div around which I want to put anchor(uri segments, text, attributes)

in pure html it looks like this:

```
    <a class="a_services" href="http://justinbieber.com">
        <div id="seminar">Hello world</div>
    </a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include code in the second parameter.

```
echo anchor('http://justinbieber.com', '<div id="seminar">Hello world</div>', 'class="a_services"');
```

Comment: Actually I have practiced this way, but this seems to me not profissional way. It seems there is no other way to use this function except this way. i got other question is it possible to adapt standard html a tag to work as anchor function? I mean  <a href="controller/function/value"><div id="seminar">Hello world</div></a>?

Comment: to adapt usual a tag is simple. <a href="<?php echo site_url('controller/function/value'); ?>"><div id="seminar">Hello world</div></a>